# Can't select item in b-dropdown vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Hy I'm creating a simple dropdown using bootstrap-vue in vuejs. The Code in my component is like this :

```
<b-col sm="2">
   <b-dropdown :text="selectedItem" v-model="selectedItem">
       <b-dropdown-item>Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Another action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Something else here</b-dropdown-item>
   </b-dropdown>
   {{selectedItem}}
</b-col>
...
...
...
data () {
 return {
   selectedItem: ''
 }
}
```

The problem is I can't select any item from dropdown item. Is there something that I missed here ?
Thanks in advance

Reference :
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a `b-dropdown` does what you think it does.

Bootstrap dropdowns are like menus. They don't have `v-models`.

What you seem to be needing is a [**Form Select**](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select) instead:

```html
<b-col sm="2">
    <b-form-select v-model="selectedItem">
        <option value="Action">Action</option>
        <option value="Another action">Another action</option>
        <option value="Something else here">Something else here</option>
    </b-form-select>
    <div>selectedItem: <strong>{{ selectedItem }}</strong></div>
</b-col>
...
...
...
data () {
 return {
   selectedItem: ''
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot for your explanation Mr. acdjunior. So I missed v-model in b-dropdrown which is not available

Comment: Yeah, it isn't. Its because that's not the goal of dropdown. I think the form select does that job pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

This is a dropdown for navigation, not a `select` elem for forms. It does not support v-model and does not act like a form input.

You could use [select](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select/) instead, or if you still want to use dropdown as a form select, you could add click handler to control it.

For e.g.

```
<b-dropdown :text="selectedItem">
        <b-dropdown-item @click="selectedItem='Action'">Action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item @click="selectedItem='Another action'">Another action</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item @click="selectedItem='Something else here'">Something else here</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zky4j0zx94

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that

Comment: Work's fine with b-dropdown